# nightmarejs , hangs the browser

Tags: node.js, electron, nightmare

Please help. I do not understand what the problem is a nightmare. The essence of the application logic is as follows: in the database has a list of tasks for a nightmare, when measuring state is generated by the initialization process of a nightmare.
The problem sludyuschem, at some point in time copies of a nightmare to stop responding and hang. On the counters in the database it can be seen that they can work for longer than specified in the timeout settings nightmare.
Please tell me what could be the problem and how it can be combated.
Check the status and run:

```
const processParse = require('./processParse');
//...
r.table('arc_tasks').getAll('toParse', {index: 'status'}).changes().run(conn, (err, cursor) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            cursor.each((err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                let val = data.new_val;
                if (val !== null) {
                    val.start = Date.now();
                    processParse(val).catch(console.error); // <- this is run process nightmare
                }
            });
        });
// ...
```

An exemplary process for the code of a nightmare:
processParse:

````
// requires and etc
module.exports = exports = async function processParse(params){
    let nightmare;
    try{
        await nighmare.authentication(params.user, params.pass);
        await nightmare.goto(params.href) // .click....click....;
        let resp = await nightmare.evaluate((selector)=>{
            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                setTimeout(reject, 30000, new Error('EVAL_TIMEOUT'))
                //....
                resolve(result);
                // ... 
                reject(result);
                });
            }, params.selector);
        await nightmare.end();
    } catch(error){
        await nightmare.end();
        throw new Error('PARSER_ERROR');
    } finally {
        // save results and change state of task
    }
};

//Example statistics (RUNTIME IN SECS):
{
        "href": "https://***",
        "templName": "GetModifications",
        "runtime": 505.369
    },
    {
        "href": "https://***",
        "templName": "GetModifications",
        "runtime": 1126.206
    },
    {
        "href": "https://***",
        "templName": "GetModifications",
        "runtime": 860.733
    },
    {
        "href": "https://***",
        "templName": "GetModifications",
        "runtime": 379.539
    }```
````

Comment: There's some typos in your code — start with that?

Comment: nightmare code exemplary and not complete. here it is a part. Issues addressed rather to those who constantly work with a nightmare.

Comment: Oh, I see I didn't read that properly. I think you mean "example" not "exemplary".

Comment: exemplary = instances of
translator did not understand my typo

Comment: I assume that any action a nightmare when you send in the electron occupies it completely and the relationship between the electron and the nightmare stops working. As in a nightmare not provide any timeout in this regard, all the action promises to wait for a response, which leads to a dead process.
Now I have added the cap, but it does not always work ...

Comment: nightmareHaltKey = setTimeout((nightmare) => {
                nightmare.halt(new Error('NIGHTMARE_FORCE_KILL'));
                throw new Error('NIGHTMARE_FORCE_KILL');
            }, 120000, nightmare);